# Magento 1 module backend not found and error has not been whitelisted

Tags: magento-1.9, module, backend

Module backend not found also appear error in the log:
`DEBUG (7): Security problem: megamenu/list has not been whitelisted.`

`The screenshot below with description in  detail :`
http://prntscr.com/pa37z3

Although have set `config System -> Permission -> Blocks`
http://prntscr.com/pa390n

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue related to compilation.
Please comment includes folder from the root directory and login into the admin panel and then run compilation once and then remove comment to the includes folder.

Thanks

Comment: I run compilation but still same the problem, you can see the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/pa42tj

Comment: When comment includes folder from the root and login into the admin then it appear error, you can see the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/pa44i1 , how to can continue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please take full backup (include Source code, media and Database )
Apply Security Patch on your magento store. To check Patch update
Scan your website at. https://www.magereport.com